# dynamic loop through folders using informatica

Tags: informatica

I am new to informatica.
I would like to do below steps in sequence in informatica 9.x

1. select `comp_id` from `<table_name>` order by `comp_id`
2. loop through `comp_id` one after the other.
3. look for the folder for that `comp_id`.
4. in that file name contains the table_code
   `Ex: aml01112021.txt`......`aml` stands for table_code
   `itm01112021.txt`......`itm` stands for table_code
5. I have a table in the database with `table_code` and `table_name`

   ```
      table_code       table_name
      aml              d_aml
      itm              d_item
   ```
6. take the table code from the file name and select `table_name` for that `table_code` from the database.
7. insert that file into the respective table in the database.

this is a kind of dynamic looping using sql.
Can some one help me the steps for doing this in Informatica 9.x?

Comment: There are a lot of small tasks, so please split your question in different atomic question and describe your exact issue with each task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow below steps -

1. Shell script to list down all files into a list file. Read that file
   in SQ, add filename port to the file definition.
2. Use another SQ to read your table. Use lookup to get table code from DB.
3. Join 1 and 2 based on file name. Now you have data from both file name and table.
4. Use the table name and file name info in a router to route to multiple targets. Informatica cant insert into dynamic target tabble for file target it can. so if you have 5target table, you need to create 5 groups in router and 5 target tables.

Whole mapping should look like this -

```
SQ_FlatFile ->                            JNR -> EXP_table+file_name ->RTR ->Target_1
SQ_Table_comp_id LKPto get table_name ->   |                           |   ->Target_2
```

Comment: Koushik, Thanks for the answer, I will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: welcome, the solution need some knowledge of Infa, pls update if you have any issues.

Comment: As I am new to informatica,  having difficult to start the mapping for the source. not sure, how to start.

Comment: start by importing flat file and the table. Then start adding the transformations like joiner, expression, router, target etc.

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer is useful and I am trying the solution you explained.